# Code coverage while debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

Is there a way to enable code coverage while debugging a asp.net site (+assemblies)?

I know how to do this for Unit Tests, but not if I'm just debugging.

What I'm actually trying to do is checking which parts of the code a certain mobile app uses. So I would like to debug my localhost asp.net site while using the mobile app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could achieve your goal with the profiler that comes with Visual Studio 2010. You would have all the code called during a debug session.